# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List

Tags: apex, trigger, list

```
trigger OpportunityAmount on Opportunity (before insert) {

    List<String> stage=new List<String>();
    For(Opportunity opp:Trigger.New){
        stage.add(opp.StageName);
    }
    List<Opportunity> stageopp=[select StageName from Opportunity where StageName=:stage];
     if(stageopp.StageName =='Closed won'){////<---- Error
        for(Opportunity opp:Trigger.New){
            opp.addError('Amount field is a required field');
        }
    }

}
```

While saving above trigger, i am getting following. Please help me in this.

> Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject:
>   List

Comment: `stageopp` is list here. you can use list.fieldName ie. stageopp.StageName... you need to use `stageopp[0].StageName` this way it will check only one sobject field.. not sure what is the business requirement.

Comment: ohh typo mistake ... stageopp is list here. you can't use list.fieldName ie. stageopp.StageName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stageopp` is a list of Opportunity according to your code. You should have a for loop to access the Opportunities inside it.

```
for(Opportunity oppRec : stageopp)
{
if(oppRec.StageName =='Closed won'){
    for(Opportunity opp:Trigger.New){
        opp.addError('Amount field is a required field');
    }
}
}
```

One more thing, your SOQL query is having a where clause where it searches for stagename inside a list, so having `=` there might not work, try using `IN` instead.

```
List<Opportunity> stageopp=[select StageName from Opportunity where StageName IN :stage];
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that `stageopp` is of type list, and `stagename` is of type Opportunity, in order to access the stagename of your `stageopp` object you would need to do `stageopp[i].StageName` where i is the index